# Pros and cons of using JSON Pretty Print?

Tags: java, json, pretty-print

Currently I am in the process of analyzing the pros and cons of producing a JSON output in different formats. What, according to you, would be the pros and cons of a JSON output with pretty print and the one **without** any formatting related to pretty printing with respect to stuff like

1. Performance.
2. Serialization/Deserialization.
3. Parsing or any other criteria.

I am using Java.

Comment: Why do you need to pretty print it?

Comment: In the my current requirement manual sent by the front end team the JSON output is based on pretty printing

Comment: That doesn't make sense. JSON is not whitespace-sensitive.

Comment: So you mean there will be no side effects if there are whitespaces due to pretty print?

Comment: Nope, JSON parsers ignore it completely. There's no point in adding it in if you don't plan on reading it. Even if you do plan on reading it, it's easier to just install a browser extension or format it inside of your text editor.

Comment: OKay so that's related to parsing but in my view and as Alex Gittemeier also suggested below, whitespaces may impact on the performance if JSON is a bulky one!

Comment: The effect would probably be negligible. Test it out if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all three points you mention, it is better not to use pretty printing. The only advantage of pretty printing is that it is easer to read by a human.

Comment: I see!!  would really appreciate if you could pinpoint on the 3 points with some practical reasons..

Comment: The extra white space that is inserted has negative effects for performance (generation, parsing, and transmission time) and in addition the generator is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing any kind of profiling, I would think that having no extra whitespace would be better for performance, if only marginally. It would save some bandwidth though.

Comment: That seems true!  If JSON result is a huge one then it might act of response time!